# Unknown class in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, xcode

Why am I still getting this error when I run my iPhone app?  The file is a ViewController that I have been working to delete and replace, but it just won't die.  As far as I know, I don't have any reference (string or otherwise) to this file in my project.

- I have deleted the related file (I'm trying to get rid of it.)
- I have cleaned the project and rebuilt.
- I have "Reset Content and Settings" in my simulator.
- I have done a grep (grep -i -r "TheClassName" *) and nothing matches except my UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file.
- I have searched the code using XCode's Find/Replace tab.
- I have double checked my Build Phases and am pretty sure it isn't in there (its a large project).

Any other ideas?  I've spent way too many hours trying to figure this simple thing out; I must be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: "nothing matches except my UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" - did you try deleting this file?

Comment: Have you perhaps set the class of some UIViewcontroller in your xib to that class ?

Comment: @Daniel, wouldn't that show up in my grep since the xib files are just plain text?

Comment: @Kreiri, I deleted my user state file but nothing changed, I still have the error.

Comment: It sounds a little silly, but is it possible that you just deleted the reference to it, and the file is still lurking in your project somewhere? Try poking around your project files in Finder and see if it's still there? XCode does funny things sometimes with adding/deleting files.

Comment: @ReidBelton, I have verified by hand, with `grep`, and with `find` that the file and any references to the file do not exist within my project directory.  I have verified this on two machines.  I am 100% sure that no textual representation of TheClassName (case insensitive) exists anywhere in my project, but perhaps in binary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem after trying it on multiple machines over the course of almost 2 days!  I will not be thwarted!

I tracked the problem down to a call to setViewControllers on a UINavigationController which is called on initialization of the application.  I was always being passed 3 objects (there are 3 panes in the navigation controller).  Even though I had deleted the third object, as previously explained, three objects would always be passed in.  The class type of the first two was correct, but the third would just be a UIViewController.  Curiously, this view controller had a nibName which corresponded to the object file and Xib file that I had previously deleted.  Of course, when view was called on this borked UIViewController, it would crash since the corresponding nib had obviously been deleted.  Remember, the textual name of this object or Xib could not be found in my directory with grep, so I have absolutely no idea how in the world it came into existence when I ran my app.

So, I figured the app may not have been cleaned properly.  I double and triple checked this.  I even validated that my Workspace settings were correct (File->Project Settings->Advanced).  The app was indeed being recompiled fresh every time.

Secondly, I started thinking that perhaps the object was being set by some other means.  Working backwards, I added some breakpoints and found out that initWithCoder was being called on the parent UINavigationController--this was eventually working down to call the setViewControllers on the object and assigning the three view controllers (one of which was the offending one).  I could easily see from the call stack that the Nib file that was being loaded was deserializing something offensive.

So, I started digging into my Xib file.  Of course, the object name wasn't in the file (as expected since the grep didn't find anything).  I deleted and recreated the portion of the Xib that included my root UINavigationController.  This ended up changing the Object ID and ref within the Xib file.
Secondly, I created a new Xib and UIViewController with the same names as the one which I had previously deleted, hoping that Xcode might be happy if I created and then re-deleted them.  I then compiled, re-deleted them, updated by Xib file yet again, reverified with grep that yes, indeed, nothing existed with that name.

And it worked.  After spending multiple days on this issues, I'm fairly sure that there is a bug here in the interface builder, but do I want to revisit this problem to file a bug report?  Absolutely not...

Comment: I got this problem because I recently started making convenience constructors and had renamed my xib files. I had an old line of code trying to use the old nib (which I assume still existed in some strange way?) and had old references to lost connections.

Answer (score 6):

Check your nibs or storyboard, and make sure none of your views are set to the class!

Comment: I really think that's it...I remember having a similar error in the past and that was the problem: a view in IB was set to a class that I had deleted. Let me know if that wasn't the problem, though.

Comment: I have gone through every nib and have verified that this is not the case.  I'm not using storyboards.

Comment: Ahh, bummer...I was hoping it would be simple (don't we always?) Glad you sorted it out, though! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved an issue by name of `Custom class name of View` instead of `Custom class of ViewController`. By mistake i added like this for view as shown below.

[image]

It Should be for ViewController like this.

[image]

This is in my case, for you may be it's related with another component.

Comment: This happens a lot, it's easy to accidentally select a view instead of the surrounding viewcontroller. You have to click EXACTLY on a very thin line to select the controller.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the view class is in a framework.  Select the framework's module. Example with a CocoaPod: HSegmentControl.

[image: Example in image is with Cocoapod HSegmentControl]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you add or rename or move files around especially in folders, that when you add them you:

A.  Create Groups, not references they don't usually read in.

B.  Check the boxes for the apporpriate "Product(s) or Target(s)" you want to add the source to.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try :

I had to toggle "Inherit from Target" under the "Module" control of "Custom Class."